# Blackberry Enterprise Server 4.1x upgrades

Tags: bes

Little confused as to how the upgrade path works for Blackberry Enterprise Server Express: I'm currently running version 4.1.5.24, but am not sure if the updates are accumulative or not and how the versioning works.  i.e. should I go to 4.1.7, or do I need to install all the interim updates and/or service pack 6 (4.1.6) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the latest service pack first (you can skip service packs as they are cumulative), then the maintenance release, then interim updates. When in doubt, the release notes always tell you what's required to run the update.

Also consider migrating to BES Express 5...the lack of per user licensing fees could easily justify the labor involved.

Comment: Went through the Release Notes for the 4.1.7 Service Pack and didn't see upgrade instructions, etc. but thanks for this.

Comment: +1 to parent. Using BES Express 5 and loving it. Migrating blackberries was pretty simple as well.